# Store Solr analyzer result in separate field

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a field type with multiple analyzers (Keepword, Synonym, ...). 
How can I store the result of all the analyzers into a separate field ?

Unfortunately, copyField is executed before the analyzers run...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The result of "all the analyzers" is the actual result stored in the field. You'll have to create separate fields that cut of the sequence of analyzers/filters earlier for each field type, then `copyField` into each field.

If you just want to watch what each step in the analysis process does, use the Admin interface and select *Analysis*. You can also access these results in a programmatic fashion through the end point that the Admin interface uses:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/analysis/field?wt=json&analysis.showmatch=true&analysis.fieldvalue=foo&analysis.query=foo&analysis.fieldname=fieldname
```

Comment: What I am seeing and what the documentation says:
Field Values versus Indexed Terms - 
The output of an Analyzer affects the terms indexed in a given field (and the terms used when parsing queries against those fields) but it has no impact on the stored value for the fields. For example: an analyzer might split "Brown Cow" into two indexed terms "brown" and "cow", but the stored value will still be a single String: "Brown Cow"

What I am interested in is in the agove example the split terms "brown" and "cow"

Comment: @tohoe If you only need them for a single request, you can use the Admin interface - or you can parse the output from the command above. Or use the [Term Vector Component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Term+Vector+Component).